# Boot windows with remote access on external hardrive

Tags: windows

I just replaced my laptop's hard drive with a new ssd that's running arch. I want to be able to set up my old hard drive (which was running windows 10) so that I can remotely access it. Is it possible with a raspberry pi? Or are there any alternatives?

Comment: Have you put any effort into doing basic research on this? This is one of the most common projects done with the RPi online...

Answer (score 1):

If you get an USB to SATA External Hard Drive Bay [like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LS5NFQ2) it should be no problem to attach it to a raspberry pi and share it via samba and lan/wlan.

An off topic alternative is a NAS case without drive [like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EVQMXZ8)

The links are no hardware recommendations, only examples of the enclosures I refer to.

Comment: is it possible to boot windows still? @LotPings

Comment: You may boot windows from an USB drive connected to the pc you relocated the drive from, but this question is now heavily off topic. Booting off a USB disk connected to a remote pc won't work.

Comment: I should have provided more information. I mean like have the raspberry pi boot windows such that I can remotely access windows. @lotPings

Comment: The arm architecture based raspberry pi can't boot a windows from a x86/AMD64 based pc. The Windows IoT running on the raspberry pi is a totally different thing.